# mysql + PHP - usar ou não usar o mysqli_close()

Tags: php, mysql, conexão

Reparei agora que não estou usando a função `mysqli_close()` indicada no site do [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.close.php)

Eu monitoro as conexões pelo [Workbench client conections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-client-connections.html) e não fica conexões abertas, minha dúvida é se dessa maneira que estou programando sem usar essa função fico propenso a algum tipo de problema no futuro tipo fulnerabilidade, erro, ou algum outro tipo de problema ?

Comment: Sua conexão ficará aberta.

Comment: no Workbench não mostra conexões em aberto

Comment: Então boa. Já era.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conexões que não são persistentes fecham-se sozinhas no final do script na teoria você não precisa fecha-la.

Mas se o seu script levar muito tempo para ser executado, é interessante que feche a conexão após usa-la para não ficar segurando ela aberta enquanto o script roda.

Isso é bom também quando seu servidor tem um número de conexões com banco limitadas.

Comment: então não tem problema além dessas questões de conexões limitadas no BD ?

Comment: Tirando essas questões que eu falei não, se o script for entregue rápido você não deve ter problemas.