# Fechar ou não conexão PHP e ASP?

Tags: php, mysql, asp

Fazendo minhas aplicações em ASP faço um include no final de todas as páginas desconectando o banco.

Em PHP é preciso desconectar também? outra questão: Como fechar essa conexão PHP?

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
$banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao,'meu-banco');
```

Comment: Essa pergunta já [tem essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83937/45810) e [essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/329891/45810).

Comment: Rod e @LipESprY creio que ambos links não estão incorretos, mas não abordam o problema real sobre abrir e fechar ou persistir conexões, creio que de longe alguém conseguiu entender que o problema é de fato a estratégia de quando manter uma conexão aberta e de quando fechar prematuramente, tentei responder em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/376418/3635, se tiverem alguma duvida ou discordância as perguntas para melhoria ou até criticas são bem vindas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que talvez na documentação não tenha ficado bem claro, não é questão de fechar no final com `mysqli_close` ou automaticamente, o que a [**documentação**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) quer dizer é que é recomendado fechar quando **não estiver** mais usando, ou seja se não vai mais usar feche.

Imagine que tem um script que demora de processar, mas precisa somente dos resultados do banco no começo, isso iria ficar segurando a conexão com o banco até o script terminar, mesmo que coloque `mysqli_close` no final do script. **Em um script demorado**, se fechar logo após pegar o resultado do banco e o resto do processo longo seguir, provavelmente irá ajudar a melhorar da performance do servidor do banco.

Agora se for usar em mais de um local de seu script **não tem sentido fechar e reabrir**, seria melhor manter aberto, pois até o tempo de fechar e reabrir pode ser algo relativamente custoso (nem sempre), tem que analisar com calma como desenvolveu o seu script e ver a necessidade, na maior parte dos casos se vai usar no começo e no fim "deixar aberto" e o script matando automaticamente a conexão (o que é natural para eles) já resolve, mas haverá casos isolados aonde provavelmente só precisa usar em uma parte do script, eu iria até mais longe, na verdade é um erro que vejo que a maioria (**a maioria mesmo**) comete, as pessoas conectam com bancos (mysql, sqlserver, etc) sem precisar, por exemplo, criam um `header.php` e colocam lá algo como:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
?>
<nav>
...
</nav>
```

E em todas páginas algo como:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<?php require 'header.php'; ?>
...
```

Resumindo, em qualquer página sempre está ocorrendo uma conexão ao banco e muitas delas podem ser desnecessárias, pois nem toda página vai acessar algo, ou vai precisar naquele momento.

O ideal seria conectar apenas se for necessário requisitar algo, um exemplo bastante simplório seria usar com cautela, fazendo uma função para conectar bastante simples:

```
function my_query($query)
{
     static $link;

     if (!$link) {
          $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
     }

     return mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

**Isso é apenas um exemplo ilustrativo**, a ideia é apenas explicar que a conexão só será feita se uma query for necessária, o que iria executar algo como:

```
$result = my_query($query);
```

Devido ao `static` a função irá conectar e manter na variável ali o resultado, claro que ali é um exemplo não muito bom de implementação, é apenas ilustrativo mesmo, existe várias formas de fazer, mas a questão é você entender que o problema não é só fechar no começo ou o quanto antes possível, é fechar se não for mais usar, para que isso não se torne um cliente a mais no servidor do seu banco.

Sem conexões desnecessárias com certeza o vosso servidor do banco irá ter menos trabalho e provavelmente irá responder melhor.

Comment: +1 pela parte em que diz: "*- um erro que vejo que a maioria (a maioria mesmo) comete"*. Já cometi esse erro me baseando em inúmeros artigos que cometem esse mesmo erro. Acabamos "seguindo" sem pensar. Foi super interessante comentar na sua resposta! Aliás, acho que seria útil mesclar as respostas dessa e das outras perguntas que mencionei no meu comentário lá em cima...

Comment: Obrigado caro @LipESprY! Sobre o mesclar, fiquei um pouco confuso, poderia explicar melhor a sua sugestão? Grato mais uma vez

Comment: Mesclar seria transformar as três perguntas em uma única e juntar todas as respostas (ou então marcar duas como duplicatas da terceira) já que todas se tratam do mesmo assunto: fechar ou não conexão com o banco de dados (e todas são sobre PHP e MySQL, além do ASP como bônus desta). Mas isso é um serviço pra moderação. O máximo que posso(dia) fazer era comentar os links das outras duas a fim de relacioná-las. Perceba que sua resposta responde as três perguntas, mas se um leitor cair nas outras duas, ele vai perder o conteúdo desta. 

Comment: @LipESprY a sim, faz todo sentido mesmo marcar como dup (que já existe nas ferramentas do site), eu posso fazer isso sem aprovação de outros votos, mas prefiro esperar a intenção dos demais participantes da comunidade. Mas sua ideia sobre isto com certeza será o melhor, vou conversar com o pessoal amanhã e verei se concordam. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Concluo que marcar como duplicata talvez seja uma melhor opção já que os mecanismos de buscas já indexaram as outras páginas. A menos que a moderação crie um redirecionamento nos endereços das três páginas. Aí é com eles. ;D

Comment: Eu pensei na mesclagem de uma e dup na outra, mas precisaria ler tudo com muita calma. Provavelmente só vou ver isso mais para o final do dia. cc @LipESprY

Answer (score 0):

Para encerrar uma conexão, utilize a função *mysqli_close*:

```
mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Direto da documentação:

> Conexões não-persistentes do MySQL e conjuntos de resultados são destruídos automaticamente quando um script PHP termina sua execução. Portanto, embora fechar explicitamente as conexões abertas e liberar os conjuntos de resultados seja opcional, isso é recomendado. Isso retornará imediatamente recursos para PHP e MySQL, o que pode melhorar o desempenho. Para informações relacionadas, consulte liberando recursos

Fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: Show, não é preciso mas é recomendado. Então vou fechar como faço em ASP. Valeu.

Comment: Isso é uma meia verdade. Tem que entender o contexto todo, pois se precisar do recurso logo em seguida pode ser mais custoso abrir nova conexão. Além disso, variáveis do MySQL, transações, last id são armazenados por sessão/conexão, então fechar e abrir novamente uma conexão pode ser um bug dependendo do caso (assim como deixar aberta é errado em outros contextos por se tratar de um recurso limitado).